# tcolorbox title on top and on bottom with centered text

Tags: tcolorbox, frame-title

I want to put a title at the bottom right of the frame and still have normal title on the top left.

My *hack* solution of using `\tcbsubtitle[after={\vspace*{-34pt}}]{}` seems to work but it messes up the `valign=center` for the box content:

[image]

So, what is the correct way to have both titles as well as having text vertically centered in the box.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
        title={Top Title},
        halign=center,
        valign=center,
        nobeforeafter,
        height=3cm,
    ]
        Some text%
        \tcbsubtitle[after={\vspace*{-34pt}}]{\hfill End-Title}% <-- Note: \vspace hack!
    \end{tcolorbox}%
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that using the lowerpart as a subtitle is the only solution. The subtitle is a new colorbox inside the colorbox. In the tcolorbox **documentation at page 22** is written that **"upperpart is mandatory"** so it cannot be suppressed.
I came up with a similar solution:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[space to upper,
        skin=bicolor,
        colbacklower=black!75,
        collower=white,
        title={Top Title},
        halign=center,
        valign=center,
        nobeforeafter,
        halign lower=flush right,
        bottom=0mm,
        height=3cm
    ]
        Some text 3cm%

        \tcblower
        End-Title
    \end{tcolorbox}%

     \begin{tcolorbox}[space to upper,
        skin=bicolor,
        colbacklower=black!75,
        collower=white,
        title={Top Title},
        halign=center,
        valign=center,
        nobeforeafter,
        halign lower=flush right,
        bottom=0mm,
        height=6cm
        ]
        Some text 6cm%

        \tcblower
        End-Title
     \end{tcolorbox}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: With `height=3cm` this solution dows not work properly as it appplies he height to the lower box.

Comment: The "space to upper" option was needed, as described in the package documentation.
I think it is OK now.

Comment: Yep, seems to work now.

Answer (score 2):

While someone finds a better solution and if your `tcolorbox` has no lower part, you can try to make the end title with the lower part in a bicolor box.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tcolorbox}[
          enhanced,
          bicolor,
        title={Top Title},
        halign=center,
        valign=center,
        nobeforeafter,
        height=3cm,
        colbacklower = black!75!white,
        halign lower = right,
        collower=white,
        space to upper,
        bottom = 0pt,
    ]
        Some text
        \tcblower
        End Title
    \end{tcolorbox}%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This other "hack" could be useful

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
\tcbset{
  experimental split/.code={
  \let\tcb@split@SL=\tcb@split@L},
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tcolorbox}[%
  experimental split,
  breakable,
  bicolor,
  collower=white,
  halign=center,
  valign lower=top,
  toptitle=1.5mm,
  bottomtitle=1.5mm,
  title={Top Title},
  colbacklower=black!75,
  ]%

  %\lipsum[1]
  Some text

  \tcblower
  \hfill End-Title
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```

I took the idea from [Breaking tcolorbox between upper and lower part](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/357908/breaking-tcolorbox-between-upper-and-lower-part).
Here is the customized `tcolorbox` with some text

[image]

Comment: With `height=3cm` this solution dows not work properly as it appplies he height to the lower box.